# Unable to add springjunit4classrunner as tag synonym for spring-test

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonym-process

I am the maintainer of the [spring-test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-test) tag; however, I cannot *suggest* the  [springjunit4classrunner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/springjunit4classrunner) tag as a synonym for [spring-test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-test).

Whenever I attempt to do so, the system says, "Version specific synonyms can only be created by moderators."

The Stack Overflow Team has instructed me to request assistance here on *Meta*.

As the author of the `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` I can vouch that `springjunit4classrunner` is not a *version specific synonym* but rather is supported by all versions of the *Spring TestContext Framework*.

Can a moderator here therefore add this synonym for me?

Comment: Related http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157869/213575

Answer (score 1):

I've suggested the synonym.

Those with a score of 5 or more in [spring-test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-test) will be able to vote for the synonym suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/spring-test/synonyms).